# How to send instant notification to smartphones over LAN with no internet

Tags: android, ios, notifications, push-notification, instant-messaging

I have a situation where I want my computer in my local network to send a notification (push notification, SMS or whatever) to either an IOS of Android device that is on this same LAN. The trick is that I want to send this notification only when the LAN connection to the internet goes down. This means of course that my LAN cannot communicate with email servers, it cannot communicate with any APNs or GCMs, etc.

Is there any way to do this? My computer (the sender) is a Linux box and it will know the local IP addresses for any IOS or Android devices locally.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is possible.

You either need:

A) A server on the LAN to connect to, that the app knows about (compile-time or runtime configurable). The apps can connect to the server to exchange data, including messages. The server might be HTTPS, and the clients might poll every 5 seconds, or something more refined - using WebSockets.

OR

B) A peer-to-peer scheme. This can get quite complex, particularly given the varying nature of networking for mobile operating systems. As an extreme, you could use UDP for multicasting to multiple devices.

These are just two general examples, and you would need to research how to implement them for your needs. You should start with [A] for prototyping.